# Friendly ID Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /articles/test-category/article-name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

**summary**

I'm getting this error after creating a rake task to import our articles in quickly on the server. I am using the following way of grabbing the article from the url:

```
@article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

**I'm using**

```
gem "friendly_id", "~> 5.0.4"
```

**error**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /articles/test-category/article-name
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=article-name
```

**lib/tasks/populate_article_data.rake:**

```
namespace :populate_article_data do

  desc "populate all article tables with data from csvs. pass in the path of your csvs like this: /Users/veronicacoulombe/Desktop/git/circuly/circuly/csvs/articles/"
  task :execute, [:path_of_csvs] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts "You are running the populate_article_data rake task in the #{Rails.env} environment"

    puts 'INITIATING DESTRUCTION of all article, category and tab tables (categories, tags, articles, articles_tags, article_translations, category_translations, tag_translations'
    Article.destroy_all
    Category.destroy_all
    Tag.destroy_all
    puts 'DESTRUCTION complete'

    categories = "copy categories from '#{args[:path_of_csvs]}categories.csv' delimiter ',' csv;"

    tags = "copy tags from '#{args[:path_of_csvs]}tags.csv' delimiter ',' csv;"

    articles = "copy articles from '#{args[:path_of_csvs]}articles.csv' delimiter ',' csv;"

    articles_tags = "copy articles_tags from '#{args[:path_of_csvs]}articles_tags.csv' delimiter ',' csv;"

    puts 'INITIATING COPYING of all article, category and tab tables from CSVS (categories, tags, articles, articles_tags, article_translations, category_translations, tag_translations'
    results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(categories)
    results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(tags)
    results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(articles)
    results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(articles_tags)

    puts 'COPYING complete'

    # didn't work
    # alter_articles = 'ALTER TABLE "articles" ADD CONSTRAINT "articles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE'
    # alter_tags = 'ALTER TABLE "tags" ADD CONSTRAINT "articles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE'
    # alter_categories = 'ALTER TABLE "categories" ADD CONSTRAINT "articles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE'
    # results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(alter_articles)
    # results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(alter_tags)
    # results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(alter_categories)
  end
end
```

**articles_controller.rb:**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show]


  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.order(id: :desc)
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  private

  def set_article
    @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :category

    extend FriendlyId 
    friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :globalize]

    # Try building a slug based on the following fields in
    # increasing order of specificity.
    def slug_candidates
      [
        :name
      ]
    end
end
```